# How can I save the comments to a site?

Tags: wordpress

I have this site

[link](http://www.sofiaclara.com/)

On this website there are about 700 comments ... the problem is that users can not give reply to this comment.

[Here](http://coment.dac-proiect.ro/index.php/2015/08/10/hello-world/) for example, each user can give one reply to comment.

I installed a plugin to do this.

I want to know if the same plugin and install main site ... the comments are deleted?

Is there any possibility to save the comments?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The Comments will be saved in the Database and will not be deleted. Just to make sure if that's right, Can you tell what Plugin are you using?